# QGIS printcomposer add reference to preset

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I make a visibility preset, I can use it in the template composer to 'lock' the layer styles.

I was wondering if I could use it as a variable in a textbox to display the name of the preset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's a direct method but you can get the preset name to some extent by calling the [presets()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVisibilityPresetCollection.html#a77a244e81838c89c06e00861badf0432) function in the [QgsVisibilityPresetCollection](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVisibilityPresetCollection.html) class (note that this returns all presets).

---

Example:

1. I created a single preset called "New_preset_example":

   [image: Preset example]
2. Then in the **Print Composer**, I created a label, went to `Item properties > Main properties > Insert an expression... > Function Editor` and used the following code to define a function to return all presets:

   ```
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *

   @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
   def preset(feature, parent):
       return str(QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection().presets())
   ```

   [image: Label properties]
3. Click *Load* then enter as the expression:

   ```
   preset()
   ```

   Or from the `Main properties`:

   ```
   [%preset()%]
   ```

   [image: Result]